# Livewire queue job dispatch afterRespone() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to dispatch a job to the sync driver and run it after the page is rendered. Then status updates are send to the frontend using Laravel Echo.

The job class is created and working.
Livewire component is working.
Echo is working.

I am trying to call the dispatch from a livewire component after a form submit.

So what happens that is not working is afterResponse part.

```php
    // This inside the livewire component
    ImportJob::dispatchAfterResponse( $data );
    // OR tried both
    dispatch( new ImportJob( $data ) )->afterResponse();
```

Both of them work and start the job what they do not do is afterResponse part.

if I chain the call into a non existing method it does render the page first, but of course then trows a error that there is no noneExistingMethod on null when the job is finished.

```php
    ImportJob::dispatchAfterResponse( $data )->nonExistingMethod();
```

Edit to clearify.

The issue is that the livewire component waits for the job to be finished before rendering the page.
If I open the same page twice and submit one I can see the status updates come in one by one but on the page that submited the form the status updates are rendered all at onces after the job finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make the job running in async mode.
I had the same issue and i solved using queue.
Something like this in ur livewire component will work:

```
ImportJob::dispatch( $data )->onQueue('default')
```

more infos here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues